# Every possible combination of a multi-list

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, generator, python-itertools

```
list_a = [("A","<",1), ("A","==",5)]
list_b = [("B","<",5), ("B","==",7), ("B",">=",8)]
list_c = [("C","<",10),("C","<=",6),("C",">",4),("C","<=",6)]
```

I want to make a list of every possible combination with constraint of only one per list admissible.

I can see that itertools.product is somewhat close to what I want, and I know that I could do something like

```
new_list = []
for a in list_a:
  for b in list_b:
    for c in list_c
      new_list.append(list(itertools.combinations([a,b,c],2)))
```

But the `n**3` complexity here seems like an incredibly poor solution given that I look to do this with eventually 9 lists (i.e., list_c, list_d, list_e, etc...) of size 30+ 
Here are some acceptable possible outputs:

```
[("A","<",1)]
[("A","<",1),("B","<",5)]
[("A","<",1),("B","==",7)]
[("A","<",1),("B",">=",8)]
[("A","<",1),("B",">=",8),("C","<",10)]
```

basically I understand usage of the itertools when you have a select set of numbers, and for example itertools.product(('ABCD'),3) would give outputs of AAA,AAB,AAC,AAD,BAA,BAB,BAC,etc, but I can't seem to figure out how to apply the "only one per list" constraint using the stdlib to the maximal extend without hacking some terribly inefficient solution.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your "one per list" restriction?  Are you saying that in each resulting combination, only one element of any of the input lists can be present?  In other words, no resulting combination can have contain 2+ elements from the same original list?

Comment: Imagine list_a=[('a',1),('a',2)], list_b=[('b',3),('b',4)]. Then the accepted outputs would be [[('a',1)],[('a',2)],[('b',3)],[('b',4)],[('a',1),('b',3)],[('a',1),('b',4)],[('a',2),('b',3)],[('a',2),('b',4)]]

Comment: I'm not sure what complexity has to do with it.  If you want every possible sequence where you choose either zero or one element from every one of your lists, then there are way too many possibilities for you to iterate over in your ultimate 9-list of 30+ element case.

Comment: Really? Why? Isn't it just 30**9 as an upper bound

Comment: "Just 30**9?"  That's 19683000000000.  Even if you could do something with 1M of them a second, that's ~230 days of computation.   (And there are a few more to consider of size < 30; if the lengths are ~35 it'll take 4x longer; etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

```
import itertools

list_a = [("A","<",1), ("A","==",5)]
list_b = [("B","<",5), ("B","==",7), ("B",">=",8)]
list_c = [("C","<",10),("C","<=",6),("C",">",4),("C","<=",6)]

lists = [list_a, list_b, list_c]


for l in lists: l.insert(0, None)

for x in itertools.product(*lists):
    print list(filter(None, x))
```

For those lists I get 60 elements, including an empty element.

For reference, the index of your example elements are listed below:

```
[("A","<",1)]                           # 20
[("A","<",1),("B","<",5)]               # 25
[("A","<",1),("B","==",7)]              # 30
[("A","<",1),("B",">=",8)]              # 35
[("A","<",1),("B",">=",8),("C","<",10)] # 36
```

Comment: Hey I didn't downvote you for what it's worth, I'll upvote you now to prove it

Comment: I know that StackOverflow is only for Q&A, but do you mind explaining what the star does in the context of the generator "for x in itertools.product" part? I don't understand what the dual l.insert(0, None) and filter(None, X) does and how it gives the solution for the problem, I'd appreciate some more feedback. Thanks again for your help

Comment: Sure, `product` expects each iterable to be passed as a separate argument.  So I could have written `product(list_a, list_b, list_c)`, but since I already gathered those into a variable `lists`, I just [**unpacked**](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) it.  I'm prepending a `None` value to each of the lists to account for the case where no elements come from that list.  The issue with this approach is that the output of `product` will have those `None` elements in the output element when no element was chosen from a given list.

Comment: (cont'd) To get rid of them I used [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter), which effectively removes the `None` values.

Comment: How does *lists in itself unpack? I'm familiar with pattern matching coming from an Erlang background, and I read the docs about unpacking, but its not like youre doing a,b,*c = [1,2,3,4,5,6] giving c the value [3,4,5,6]

Comment: Imagine a function defined as `def foo(a,b)` if I had a list `lst=[2,3]`, I could unpack it by calling foo as `foo(*lst)`. Then, inside `foo`, `a=2, b=3`.  If I didn't unpack it with the asterisk (e.g. `foo(lst)`), I would get an error since I only passed one argument and the function expected two.  Does that help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72478/discussion-between-arthur-colle-and-jedwards).